# Amazon RDS MySQL - Couldn't execute 'FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK'

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am using the exact command from [AWS docummentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Exporting.NonRDSRepl.html)

```
mysqldump -h source_MySQL_DB_instance_endpoint ^
    -u user ^
    -ppassword ^
    --port=3306 ^
    --single-transaction ^
    --routines ^
    --triggers ^
    --databases  database database2 > path\rds-dump.sql
```

But I got the error:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK': Access denied for user 'admin'@'%' (using password: YES) (1045)
```

This command only works when removing `--single-transaction` option. Why?

My MySQL RDS version is `8.0.33`

In this case, when removing `--single-transaction`, all tables are locked in Amazon RDS MySQL?

### UPDATE

Thanks @Quassnoi, added the `--set-gtid-purged=off` and solved the problem, something like it:

```
mysqldump -h source_MySQL_DB_instance_endpoint ^
    -u user ^
    -ppassword ^
    --port=3306 ^
    --single-transaction ^
    --routines ^
    --triggers ^
    --set-gtid-purged=off ^
    --databases  database database2 > path\rds-dump.sql
```

Comment: What does `mysqldump --version` return? (mysqldump version, not RDS version)

Comment: mysqldump  Ver 8.0.33-commercial for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Enterprise Server - Commercial)

Comment: do you have GTID enabled? `SELECT @@GTID_MODE` as an admin

Comment: GTID_MODE  is OFF_PERMISSIVE

Comment: Did you read the MySQL 8.0 manual? There are new privileges required for `--single-transaction` as of 8.0.32. Read it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction It's possible that AWS does not allow you to have the privileges required. This should be a tech support request to AWS.

Comment: @BillKarwin: isn't it only for when gtid is set? there was a bug a couple versions ago which would lock even if it's not set, but it should have been fixed in op's version

Comment: Is this the bug you are thinking of? https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109685 That says it was fixed in 8.0.33, but it's possible it was not fixed properly, or it's possible the OP is mistaken about the version they are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqldump` needs to lock tables even with `--single-transaction` enabled, if your server is set up to generate GTID (global transaction identifiers). It's needed to avoid certain race conditions with replication, if you load your dump to a server that's part of a replication cluster.

> The `RELOAD` or `FLUSH_TABLES` privilege is required with `--single-transaction` if both `gtid_mode=ON` and `--set-gtid=purged=ON|AUTO`. This requirement was added in MySQL 8.0.32.

If GTID is not enabled on your server (and you have specified in the comments that it's not), this is not required and `mysqldump` is not supposed to issue `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`.

There has been a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109685) which still made it lock, but is should have been fixed in 8.0.33 (the version that you're using). Maybe it's still there.

Try running the 8.1 or 8.0.31 versions of `mysqldump` and see if it fixes the issue.

If you are not using the dump for populating a replica, you can also set the variable `--set-gtid-purged` to off.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!! GTID is not enabled, but amazon rds uses the value OFF_PERMISSIVE (non-default, the default is OFF). So I tried export the database using the parameter --set-gtid-purged=off in mysqldump and it work fine now, even with --single-transacton. Could you add this information in you answer? then I will accept it.